# What is the best way to make two web pages communicate between each other back and forth?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, web

What is the best way to make two web pages communicate between each other back and forth? I will be using HTML and Javascript. Basically I want to login on a web page and I should be able to see who has logged in from the second page. It's just a test app so just need a quick solution.

Comment: Depends on the login system, generally you'd store the logged in users in a DB, and access that from the other page, but this is impossible to answer, and there probably aren't any quick solutions that works everywhere.

Comment: Can't I just do that using a Javascript variable or something? I am making this to test another application, so don't want to waste time on setting up a DB and other things.

Comment: Are the pages on the same website (as in `www.example.com`)? If not, are they on different subdomains of the same domain (as in `www.example.com` and `other.example.com`)? Or are they on completely different domains?

Comment: Can I make them all access a single JS file and use that to manipulate HTML elements on both the pages?

Comment: Js gets run on the client.  You can't do this with the client side alone

Comment: Is the second page where you want to see the logged in users on the open on the same client machine (ie same session)?

Comment: @JosephMalle I am ok with keep it on the client. It's a test app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just wanted two pages to communicate in the same browser session on the same domain, you could use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) -- it's basically a key-value store with some limits on size (rough estimate 5 MB but it varies). An [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/storage) is fired when you write to localStorage so you can have a listener on one page (and write to it from another page).

However, the constraint of needing to see who has logged in from a second page means JavaScript alone client-side is not going to be able to solve the problem. You'll need something on the server-side that you can poll (or use a push mechanism). You could use JavaScript there to continue to update a page with login data. But it needs to talk to the server to know who logged in.

Comment: While true this will completely fail for "I want to login on a web page and I should be able to see who has logged in from the second page".

Comment: @user2864740 True, I missed that part. That is going to require some server interaction. I edited!

Comment: Will this hold true even if I just want to send a string value from page A to Page B? Just a note that I want to send it while page B is loaded on a browser and I want it to trigger a JS function on page B. Can I use ajax for this?

Comment: @BrownTownCoder If both page A and B are loaded in the same browser session then you can send whatever you want via localStorage. You can even use JSON (stringify and parse) to send objects back and forth. But it has to be on the same browser session.